# Deploying >ROR 3 (version >3 ) app on phusion passenger (nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, passenger

I am a newbie and trying to learn ROR on nginx. So I installed phusion.

My stack is 
RUBY ON RAILS version: 3.2.6
NGINX version: 1.2.2
RVM version: 1.14.6 stable
MONGODB version: 2.0.6
CENTOS: 6.3
My nginx conf file can be seen at http://pastebin.com/70zYbCz3
and in attached image you can see my directory structure. Where my ror app 'mkf' is in /web/ folder.

In order to get my ror app work through phusion, I am following instructions at http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_ror_app , but this instruction is for "Deploying a Ruby on Rails 1.x or 2.x (but NOT Rails >= 3) application"

QUESTION 1: 
Since my ROR version is 3.2.6, so I am lost as I could not find any documentation/reference for newer version of ROR? I would sincerely appreciate if anyone can show the steps to follow or point to link where related info is available. I googled, but could not find any info for > ROR3 app deployment on phusion. It would be great if you can let me know the steps by refering my nginx conf file and please see the next comment below to see the screenshot of my app dir structure.

QUESTION 2: 
Also at this website guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html , "
4.1 Starting up the Web Server" 
asks for using "rails server"
to start rail server, but I dont think I need to do that once nginx is the webserver that will take care of it through phusion..right?

I have not created any symlink anywhere yet.

Thank you so much.

Comment: My app folder structure can be seen at http://www.flickr.com/photos/83111312@N02/7666307016/in/photostream/

Comment: Reg Qno-2 ..Yes you are correct. Once you setup the nginx server with passenger, you don't need to start rails server

Comment: Things to check:
passenger_root and passenger_ruby paths are available.

Comment: define the passenger instances inside http {}, it's not present in your cnf file

Comment: Skip down to the next section in the docs 'Deploying a Rack-based Ruby application (including Rails >= 3)'

Comment: Thanks GhostRider. I already have all those what you mentioned in your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @FrederickCheung , you were right. I should follow 'Deploying a Rack-based Ruby application (including Rails >= 3)' . Even Hongli Lai suggested me to do the same in phusion google group https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phusion-passenger/yehz2aJGkWk